# Filter do not refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm having refresh issues with a localization filter. When the file is loaded, the view do not get refreshed. I've tried `$scope.$apply()` and `$filter("localization")(localizationService.text)`, neither is working.

**localizationService :**

```
angular
    .module("myApp")
    .factory("localizationService", function () {
        var service = {
            text: null,
            language: "en"
        };

        return service;
    });
```

**localization filter :**

```
angular
    .module("myApp")
    .filter("localization", function(localizationService) {
        return function (value) {
            if (localizationService.text && localizationService.text.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
                return localizationService.text[value];
            }
            return value;
        }
    });
```

**controller refreshing automatically the file to use :**

```
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $location.path();
    }, function () {
        var fileName = "../Localizations/" + $location.path().substring(1) + "/localization-" + localizationService.language + ".json";

        $http.get(fileName).then(function (response) {
            localizationService.text = response.data;
            //$filter("localization")(localizationService.text);
            //$scope.$apply();
        });
    });
```

**localization-en.json :**

```
{
  "test": "this is working !"
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div>{{'test' | localization}}</div>
```

This code writes `test` instead of `this is working !`.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Looks like the filter is evaluated only once before the file is loaded... I don't get why it is not re-evaluating the filter afterwards. While a `$scope.$apply();` says : `$digest already in progress`...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ever since version **1.3.0-rc.2**, filters are by default stateless. This means that the filtered expression will only be reevaluated if the left-hand-side expression changes.

You have this:

```
<div>{{'test' | localization}}</div>
```

`test` will obviously never change in this case, so the entire expression will only be evaluated once.

You need to flag the filter as stateful:

```
app.filter("localization", function(localizationService) {

  function localization(value) {

    if (localizationService.text && localizationService.text.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
      return localizationService.text[value];
    }
    return value;
  }

  localization.$stateful = true;

  return localization;
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/YIzmH3lR9350McprusAA?p=preview